# How to get the count of distinct values until a time period Impala/SQL?

Tags: sql, impala

I have a raw table recording customer ids coming to a store over a particular time period. Using Impala, I would like to calculate the number of distinct customer IDs coming to the store until each day. (e.g., on day 3, 5 distinct customers visited so far)

Here is a simple example of the raw table I have:

```
 Day    ID
 1    1234
 1    5631
 1    1234
 2    1234
 2    4456
 2    5631
 3    3482
 3    3452
 3    1234
 3    5631
 3    1234
```

Here is what I would like to get:

```
 Day    Count(distinct ID) until that day
 1        2
 2        3
 3        5
```

Is there way to easily do this in a single query?

Comment: `(e.g., on day 3, 5 distinct customers visited so far) ` id represents the customer right?How can you say that 5 distinct customers visited the store when 1234 visited twice on day 3.You expected results doesnt really follow on what your trying to say.

Comment: From the beginning (from day 1 to day 3), you need to count customer 1234 only once. I am looking for count(distinct ID) until day 3

Comment: Then the count on day 2 should be 1. and for day 3, the count should be 2. that's why im saying your expected results doesnt follow what you are trying to say.

Comment: No, the count on day2 means count of distinct IDs until day 2 (including day 2) - which are: 1234, 5631, 4456  - three ids...sorry if it was misleading.. I think I got my answer below..Thanks for asking though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not 100% sure if will work on impala

But if you have a table days. Or if you have a way of create a derivated table on the fly on impala.

```
CREATE TABLE days ("DayC" int);

INSERT INTO days
    ("DayC")
VALUES  (1), (2), (3);
```

OR

```
 CREATE TABLE days AS
     SELECT DISTINCT "Day"
     FROM sales
```

You can use this query

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4214c/3)** in Postgresql

```
SELECT "DayC", COUNT(DISTINCT "ID")
FROM sales
cross JOIN days 
WHERE "Day" <= "DayC"
GROUP BY "DayC"
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| DayC | count |
|------|-------|
|    1 |     2 |
|    2 |     3 |
|    3 |     5 |
```

**[UPDATE VERSION](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4214c/5)**

```
SELECT T."DayC", COUNT(DISTINCT "ID")
FROM sales
cross JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT "Day" as "DayC" FROM sales) T
WHERE "Day" <= T."DayC"
GROUP BY T."DayC"
```

Answer (score -1):

try this one:

```
 select day, count(distinct(id)) from yourtable group by day
```

Comment: This will just give the count of distinct IDs in each day. I need count of distinct IDs UNTIL each day (starting from day 1)..

Comment: Impala doesn't allow you to select from columns not in your Group By statement. Which is ridiculous...